# Starting 64 bit mysql 64 bit on mac osx lion still shows 32 bit compilation

Tags: python, mysql, macos, 64-bit

I installed the dmg package mysql-5.5.21-osx10.6-x86_64.dmg from dev.mysql.com to install the 64 bit version of MySQL on my mac os x 10.7. It looks like 64 bit, but when I run:

```
mysql> SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'version_compile_machine';
+-------------------------+-------+
| Variable_name           | Value |
+-------------------------+-------+
| version_compile_machine | i386  |
+-------------------------+-------+
```

Ideally, it should show x64_64 because this is a 64 bit installation. This results in django throwing some errors because my python is a 64 bit compile and looks like MySQL is a 32 bit one. Any ideas on how to fix this?

By the way,

```
$ file /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld
/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld: Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64

[/usr/local/mysql]$ mysql --version
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.21, for osx10.6 (i386) using readline 5.1
```

So I am not sure why this is happening! I would ideally want x86_64 instead of i386 in the version_compile_machine.

Comment: Could you solve this? I am facing the same problem. I had read somewhere that you should ensure that your mac is in th 64-bit mode (using `uname -m`). I did that, but I still have the problem that you have.

Answer (score 0):

It is just a guess, but did you check that mysql, mysqld and the mysqld you are connecting to are all the same?  What could be happening is

1. In the first example you connect to a different server than /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld, maybe /bin or even a different machine.
2. Despite being in the local directory you probably call /bin/mysql in the last line of code you posted. Try `./mysql --version` instead.

Comment: Yes, I did that all of them are the same. I actually did a fresh reinstall of my 10.7 and then installed MySQL 5.5 and the same error shows up!